# Can I exclude an active joint in MoveIt! groups?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wonder if I can exclude an active joint from kinematic chain in MoveIt! configuration.

I'm trying to use Sawyer, 7DOF arm. [The sawyer MoveIt! Tutorial](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/intera/MoveIt_Tutorial) have sawyer_moveit_config which uses all joints and KDL, and it works. But 7DOF IK is a bit twitchy, so I want to try to handle it as 6DOF arm for investigation.

The easiest way is to make a joint as fixed joint in robot_description, but Sawyer setup /robot_description in the controller box so that I cannot change the description.

Is there any way to do so in MoveIt! settings? I tried passive joint, but it seems not update the joint angle, so the robot state gets incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306202/can-i-exclude-an-active-joint-in-moveit!-groups?/) by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) on 2018-10-21**:
I see, thank you! Sawyer SDK provide us joint_trajectory_controller and let us start it explicitly, so I guess it is not so differ from other system. I continue to investigate on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik this is not possible. Whether this actually works would also depend on how Sawyer handles this internally (ie: it might completely ignore what you do and just take a pose goal and do its own IK).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0